# the data stored in my sqlite data base for few days only?

Tags: android, sqlite

In my application i am using sqlit data base  for storing  user information , and these information stored successfully , but they are  stored for 2 days since i can  retrieve them during  2  days  and show them on the screen but  after 2 days or more  when i ran my app  there is no data displayed  " the returned cursor is empty when i debug my code "     i  used the DataBaseAdapter  and DatabaseHelper classes  for creating the data base ,i am really  wondering from that ,  why this problem occur ? how i can solve it ?
i believe that there is no problem  in the code since i can insert and retrieve the data and i found  my data base in data/data/my pavkage name /databases/ DBname

any body have an idea about this issue ? please help me ......

**this my code for creating the data base**

```
public class DBAdapter
 {
public static final String DB_NAME="MYDB";
private static final int DB_VERSION=5;
private static final String TRACKER_TABLE_NAME="Tracker";
private static final String EXERCISE_TABLE_NAME="Exercise";
private static final String MEAL_TABLE_NAME="Meal";
private static final String FOOD_TABLE_NAME="Food";
private static final String MEALFOOD_TABLE_NAME="MealFood";

private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Context context;

// table Exercise columns name
public static final String KEY_DATE="Date";
public static final String KEY_TIME="Time";
public static final String KEY_NAME="Name";
public static final String KEY_PERIOD="Period";
public static final String KEY_BURNEDCALS="Burned_Calories";

// table Tracker columns Name
public static final String KEY_TDATE="Date";
public static final String KEY_DAILY_BCALS_COUNTER="DialyBCalsCounter";
public static final String KEY_DAILY_NCALS_COUNTER="DialyNCalsCounter";
public static final String KEY_VB12_COUNTER="VB12Counter";
public static final String KEY_PROTEIN_COUNTER="ProteinCounter";
public static final String KEY_SODIUM_COUNTER="SodiumCounter";
public static final String KEY_IRON_COUNTER="IronCounter";
public static final String KEY_CHOLESTEROL_COUNTER="CholesterolCounter";
public static final String KEY_FAT_SAT_COUNTER="FatSatCounter";
public static final String KEY_FAT_MONO_COUNTER="FatMonoCounter";

// table Meal columns Name
public static final String KEY_MDATE="Date";
public static final String KEY_MTIME="Time";
public static final String KEY_MEALTYPE="MealType";

// table Food columns Name
public static final String KEY_FOODID="Food_ID";
public static final String KEY_FOODNAME="Food_Name";
public static final String KEY_CALORIES="Calories";
public static final String KEY_VB12="VB12";
public static final String KEY_CHOLESTEROL="Cholesterol";
public static final String KEY_PROTEIN="Protein";
public static final String KEY_IRON="Iron";
public static final String KEY_SODIUM="Sodium";
public static final String KEY_FAT_MONO="Fat_Mono";
public static final String KEY_FAT_Sat="Fat_Sat";
public static final String KEY_CARBOHYDRATE="carbohydrate";

// table MealFood columns Name
public static final String KEY_MFDATE="Date";
public static final String KEY_MFTIME="Time";
public static final String KEY_MFMEALTYPE="MealType";
public static final String KEY_MFFOODID="Food_ID";


private static final String EXERCISE_TABLE_CREATE ="create table Exercise (Date text not null  , "+
        "Time  text not null  ,Name  text not null," + " Period  REAL not null, Burned_Calories  REAL  not null," +
        " primary key(Date,Time ) );"  ;

private static final String Meal_TABLE_CREATE= "create table IF NOT EXISTS Meal (Date  text not null , "+
        "Time   text not null,MealType  text not null,"+ " primary key(Date,Time ,MealType) );" ;

private static final String FOOD_TABLE_CREATE= "create table IF NOT EXISTS Food (Food_ID  INTEGER  primary key  AUTOINCREMENT  , "+
        "Food_Name   text not null,Calories  integer  not null,"+ "VB12   integer  not null,Cholesterol  integer  not null,"+ 
        "Protein   integer  not null,Iron integer  not null,Sodium integer  not null,Fat_Mono integer  not null,Fat_Sat integer  not null,carbohydrate integer  not null);" ;

private static final String MealFOOD_TABLE_CREATE= "create table IF NOT EXISTS MealFood (Date  text  not null , "+
        "Time   text not null,MealType  text not null,"+"Food_ID  integer   not null ,  primary key(Date,Time ,MealType,Food_ID) );" ;

private static final String TRACKER_TABLE_CREATE= "create table IF NOT EXISTS Tracker (Date  text   not null  primary key  , "+
        "DialyBCalsCounter integer  not null,DialyNCalsCounter  integer  not null,"+ 
        "VB12Counter   integer  not null,ProteinCounter  integer  not null,"+ "SodiumCounter  integer  not null,IronCounter integer  not null,"+
        "CholesterolCounter  integer  not null );" ;    

 public DBAdapter(Context ctxt)
    {
    this.context=ctxt;
    DBHelper= new DatabaseHelper(context);
       }

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context    context)
    {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        try
        {
            db.execSQL(EXERCISE_TABLE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(TRACKER_TABLE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(Meal_TABLE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(FOOD_TABLE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(MealFOOD_TABLE_CREATE);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        //          Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version" + oldVersion +" to "+ newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");     
        //          db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Exercise");
        //          db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Food");
        //          db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Meal");
        //          db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MealFood");
        //          
        //          onCreate(db);
    }
}   

//--open the DB
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//---closes the database---
public void close()
{
    DBHelper.close();
}
//---insert   Exercise info to the Exercise table---
public long SaveExecise(String date ,String  time,String name ,float  period, float BurnedCalories)
{
    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
    content.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    content.put(KEY_TIME, time);
    content.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    content.put(KEY_PERIOD,period);
    content.put(KEY_BURNEDCALS, BurnedCalories);

    return db.insert(EXERCISE_TABLE_NAME, null, content);
}       

// retrieve  ex_Name  ,ex_period, ex_burned cals of all exercises played in a specific date  
public Cursor getExerciseInfo(String  date) throws SQLException
{
    Cursor  C_excer = db.query(EXERCISE_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {KEY_NAME,KEY_PERIOD,KEY_BURNEDCALS},
            KEY_DATE + " = '" + date + "'", null, null, null, null);
    //if (C_excer != null) {
    C_excer.moveToFirst();
    //}
    return C_excer;
}

// insert meal info to the meal table 
public long SaveMeal(String date , String time , String mealType)
{
    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
    content.put(KEY_MDATE,date);
    content.put(KEY_MTIME,time);
    content.put(KEY_MEALTYPE,mealType);
    return db.insert(MEAL_TABLE_NAME, null, content);

}

// insert Food info to the Food table 
public long SaveFood(String name,int calories,int Vit_B12,int cholesterol,int protein ,int iron ,int sodium,int Fat_Mono,int Fat_Sat,int carbohydrate)
{
    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();

    content.put(KEY_FOODNAME,name);
    content.put(KEY_CALORIES,calories);
    content.put(KEY_VB12,Vit_B12);
    content.put(KEY_CHOLESTEROL,cholesterol);
    content.put(KEY_PROTEIN,protein);
    content.put(KEY_IRON,iron);
    content.put(KEY_SODIUM,sodium);
    content.put(KEY_FAT_MONO,Fat_Mono);
    content.put(KEY_FAT_Sat,Fat_Sat);
    content.put(KEY_CARBOHYDRATE,carbohydrate);


    return db.insert(FOOD_TABLE_NAME, null, content);

}

// get food id by its name   

public int getFoodIDByName(String name) throws SQLException
{    int id =0;
Cursor cursor=db.query(true,FOOD_TABLE_NAME, new String[]{KEY_FOODID},  KEY_FOODNAME+ " = '" + name + "'", null, null, null, null,null);
if (cursor != null) {
    cursor.moveToLast();

    id=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_FOODID));

}
cursor.close();
cursor.deactivate();
return id;

}


// insert mealFood info  to mealFood table 
public long SaveMealFood(String date , String time , String mealType, int Food_id)
{
    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
    content.put(KEY_MFDATE,date);
    content.put(KEY_MFTIME,time);
    content.put(KEY_MFMEALTYPE,mealType);
    content.put(KEY_MFFOODID,Food_id);
    return db.insert(MEALFOOD_TABLE_NAME, null, content);
}
// get  specific meal foodID from mealFood table
public Cursor  getSpecificMealFoodsID(String date,String mealType) throws SQLException
{
    Cursor cursor=db.query(true,MEALFOOD_TABLE_NAME, new String[]{KEY_MFFOODID},KEY_MFDATE+ " = '" + date + "'"+ " "+ "and" +" "+ KEY_MFMEALTYPE+ " = '" + mealType + "'", null, null, null, null,null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;

}



//get food name,cals from food table based on the food id that we get it from the mealFood table    
public Cursor  getFoodNameAndCals(int food_id) throws SQLException
{
    Cursor cursor=db.query(true,FOOD_TABLE_NAME, new String[]{KEY_FOODNAME,KEY_CALORIES},KEY_FOODID+"="+food_id, null, null, null, null,null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    return cursor;


}




public Cursor getAllFoods() throws SQLException
{ 
    Cursor food_Cursor = db.query(FOOD_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {KEY_FOODID, KEY_FOODNAME,KEY_CALORIES}, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (food_Cursor  != null) {
        food_Cursor .moveToFirst();
    }
    return food_Cursor ;
}

// retrieve all store exercises // for testing 
public Cursor getExerciseInfo() throws SQLException
{
Cursor  C_excer = db.query(EXERCISE_TABLE_NAME, new String[] 
      {              
         KEY_NAME,KEY_PERIOD,KEY_BURNEDCALS},null, null, null, null, null);
    //if (C_excer != null) {
    C_excer.moveToFirst();
    //}
 return C_excer;}
}
```

In my application activities i just used the methods for inserting and retrieving data 
what i should do to prevent the recreation of the data base in each time i ran the app ?
since i think its true what you are saying , please  help me

Comment: SQLite doesn't just delete its contents every two days. You'll have to check your code to see where you are doing this. Perhaps you are deleting old data somewhere? Recreating the database when you think you are initializing it?

Comment: Post code if you want help, we're not mind-readers

Comment: As @Panagiotis Kanavos suggested, my guess would also be that you are recreating the database.

Comment: i didnt implement and use any method to delete the data but i think that you are true about that i  recreate the database while i think that i  initialize it , since  when i  ran my app and  insert to the  data base it insert from  beginning  to the tables "  the returned number of the inserted row is 1 it didnt complete  inserting to the table" i will post my code for crating my data base , and  the methods for inserting and retrieving data if that will help

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos  thank you ,  i posted my code  you can see it , what i should do to prevent the recreation of my data base ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with your code.  Has your code in the `onUpgrade` method always been commented out?

My guess would be you incremented the database version, which triggered the `onUpgrade` method and deleted your tables then re-created them (assuming that that code hasn't always been commented out).

Comment: onUpgrade method code is always as comment

Comment: is there another possible thing that cause the  data base recreation ?

Comment: please help me what can i do?

Comment: Uninstalling and re-installing the app would have the same effect.  You didn't say if this was in the emulator or not, but if it is the emulator and you have the option to "wipe user data" checked then that is the same as deleting the app and re-installing (thus re-creating the database).  I don't see any delete functions, so it can't be one of those gone wrong.